# Error with Installing PowerToys in Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, windows-10-desktop

I get this error when I try to install Powertoys（PT） on my laptop (Windows 10 Pro 64-bit version).
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8wxf.png)

Details:
・I was installing the latest version of PT（0.64.1）
・Using Github Installer
・Ran it as admin

Here is what I have tried on my part on PowerToys (PT) installation so far:
・I ran the X64 installer from the GitHub page (I also tried the ARMProcessor version but I get the same error.)
Does the fact that running both files (X64 and ARMProcessor set-up) gives the same error mean that it's a windows issue?

・Tried installing 「.NET 6.0.10 Desktop Runtime　（dotnet-sdk-6.0.403-win-x64）」
・Running the set-up as admin （Note: I am the admin on my laptop, I have just one User account）
・Tried installing the windows troubleshooter （MicrosoftProgram_Install_and_Uninstall.meta.diagcab）before installing PT
・Ran the DISM scan, sfc/scannow, etc.
・Based on some comments online I tried installing .NET4.0.13 （windowsdesktop-runtime-5.0.13-win-x64）before installing PT as well but it didn't work.

Is there anything else that I can try?

Below is the content of the Error Log file, any help is appreciated.

````
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallFolder' to value '[ProgramFiles64Folder]PowerToys'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Initializing string variable 'MsiLogFolder' to value '[LocalAppDataFolder]\Microsoft\PowerToys'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Initializing version variable 'DetectedPowerToysVersion' to value '0.0.0.0'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Initializing version variable 'TargetPowerToysVersion' to value '0.64.1'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Initializing version variable 'DetectedWindowsBuildNumber' to value '0'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\Users\Manoj\Downloads\PowerToysSetup-0.64.1-x64.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=592 -burn.filehandle.self=600'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\Manoj\Downloads\PowerToysSetup-0.64.1-x64.exe'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\Manoj\Downloads'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\powertoys-bootstrapper-msi-0.64.1_20221126121849.log'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'PowerToys (Preview) x64'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft Corporation'
[4360:2E34][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WixStdBALanguageId' to value 1033
[4360:2E34][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '0.64.1.0'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i100: Detect begin, 4 packages
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Product or related product not found: {42B84BF7-5FBF-473B-9C8B-049DC16F7708}
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Setting version variable 'DetectedPowerToysVersion' to value '0.0.0.0'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Setting string variable 'DetectedWindowsBuildNumber' to value '17134'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: File search: wfsC3EC23730ACEC87BFF4A5D607E1BEEAD, did not find path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\6.0.10\System.Xaml.dll
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Setting numeric variable 'HasDotnet6010' to value 0
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Setting numeric variable 'HasWebView2PerUser' to value 0
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}'
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i000: Setting numeric variable 'HasWebView2PerMachine' to value 0
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i052: Condition 'HasDotnet6010' evaluates to false.
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i052: Condition 'HasWebView2PerMachine OR HasWebView2PerUser' evaluates to false.
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i101: Detected package: TerminatePowerToys, state: Absent, cached: None
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i101: Detected package: DotnetRuntime6, state: Absent, cached: None
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i101: Detected package: WebView2, state: Absent, cached: None
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i101: Detected package: PowerToysSetup_0.64.1_x64.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i052: Condition 'TargetPowerToysVersion >= DetectedPowerToysVersion OR WixBundleInstalled' evaluates to true.
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i052: Condition 'DetectedWindowsBuildNumber >= 19041 OR WixBundleInstalled' evaluates to false.
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]e000: This application is only supported on Windows 10 version v2004 (build 19041) or higher.
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]e000: Error 0x81f40001: Bundle condition evaluated to false: DetectedWindowsBuildNumber >= 19041 OR WixBundleInstalled
[4360:3704][2022-11-26T12:18:49]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0 ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to upgrade your Windows version. From the log file:

```
Setting string variable 'DetectedWindowsBuildNumber' to value '17134'
....
Bundle condition evaluated to false: DetectedWindowsBuildNumber >= 19041 OR WixBundleInstalled
```

Comment: Dear Rob, thank you very much. Updating the windows did the trick.

Comment: Hi, @Smalbro93. On StackOverflow you say thanks by clicking the up arrow on the question, and you say the question is answered by marking one of the answers as the answer.

Comment: I am unable to upvote the answer due to not having enough reputation but I marked the question as answered. Thank you.